# Share a printer between Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, linux, networking, printer

I have a `Canon LBP2900` printer. I have connected the printer with my desktop PC running windows xp and shared it. I have Ubuntu in my laptop and connected to the local network. Is there any easy way to print from ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Many Linux distributions use CUPS as the printer server.  You can configure it to print to the Widows print server.  I found this http://opensuse.swerdna.org/susesambaprint.html documentation.

It might be simpler to move the printer to the Linux server and configure it in CUPS.  You can then use the ImageWriter driver to print to the CUPS printer spool on the Linux side.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to enable the- LPD service on Windows.

> LPD Service
>   The Line Printer Daemon (LPD) Service installs and starts the TCP/IP Print Server (LPDSVC) service, which enables UNIX-based computers or other computers that are using the Line Printer Remote (LPR) service to print to shared printers on this server. It also creates an inbound exception for port 515 in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731857.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply install cups
Open http://localhost:631 as root
and configure printer via wizard.